# Baking a cube texture, only one face is visible?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I tried to follow a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ClzsuExtCo) on how to bake a texture, but it does not work, the second cube has only one face from the first cube, I don't understand why, is it related to the seams ?

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Were the two cubes in the same location when the texture was baked? They must intersect for the rays to hit the surface.

Comment: @Blunder great thank you !